# MLA In-text citations for websites

Tags: technique, citations, research, mla, ambiguity

I've done some research, but a lot of sources contradict each other. I was just wondering how to do embedded citations for MLA regarding websites. I wasn't too sure how to do them as the websites I use don't really have any page numbers.

How would I do it?

Would it be (Last Name, Year)?

Comment: I am putting this as a comment instead of an answer, as it is link only. I found this link for an exact answer to your question: https://www.scribbr.com/mla/website-citation/#:~:text=An%20MLA%20website%20citation%20includes,title%20of%20the%20page%20instead.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed :)

Comment: @Ian54 You should post that as an answer anyway, and just add in the relevant information from the link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Overall Website" In Citing a Website (MLA)](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/27614/overall-website-in-citing-a-website-mla)

Comment: @JoMama If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

(I had this in comments but I decided to move it to answer form.)

**All of the info and examples in this answer are taken directly from [this link](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/website-citation/#:%7E:text=An%20MLA%20website%20citation%20includes,title%20of%20the%20page%20instead)**

My answer:

If you are citing a whole website (the whole website means not a specific page, but the general information on a website), your citation should look like this:

**MLA whole website citation**

Format: Website Name, Day Month Year, URL.
Works Cited entry:  Scribbr. [www.scribbr.com](http://www.scribbr.com). Accessed 11 July 2019.
In-text citation:   (Scribbr)

If you are citing an online blog, newspaper, or magazine, use this format: (note, academic articles should have a different form of citation.)

**MLA online article citation**

Format: Author last name, First name. “Title of Article.” Website Name, Day Month Year, URL.
Works Cited entry:  Smith, Helena. “The Women Who Brought Down Greece’s Golden Dawn.” The Guardian, 22 Oct. 2020, [www.theguardian.com/­world/­2020/­oct/­22/­the-­women-­who-­brought-­down-­greeces-­golden-­dawn](http://www.theguardian.com/%C2%ADworld/%C2%AD2020/%C2%ADoct/%C2%AD22/%C2%ADthe-%C2%ADwomen-%C2%ADwho-%C2%ADbrought-%C2%ADdown-%C2%ADgreeces-%C2%ADgolden-%C2%ADdawn).
In-text citation:   (Smith)

**MLA website citation with no author**

Format: “Title of Article.” Website Name, Day Month Year, URL.
Works Cited entry:  “US Election 2020: A Guide to the Final Presidential Debate.” BBC News, 21 Oct. 2020, [www.bbc.com/­news/­election-­us-­2020-­54620868](http://www.bbc.com/%C2%ADnews/%C2%ADelection-%C2%ADus-%C2%AD2020-%C2%AD54620868).
In-text citation:   (“US Election 2020”)

**MLA website citation with no author or date**

Format: “Title of Article.” Website Name, URL. Accessed Day Month Year.
Works Cited entry:  “Citing Sources and Referencing.” Scribbr, [www.scribbr.com/­category/­citing-­sources](http://www.scribbr.com/%C2%ADcategory/%C2%ADciting-%C2%ADsources). Accessed 16 July 2019.
In-text citation:   (“Citing Sources”)

**(Note: the following information has been taken from [this website](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/journal-citation/))**

**Citing an online journal article**

When citing an online journal article, first look for a DOI, as this is more stable and less likely to change than a URL.

Example:
Ahmed, Sara. “A Phenomenology of Whiteness.” Feminist Theory, vol. 8, no. 2, Aug. 2007, pp. 149-168. doi:10.1177/1464700107078139.

Articles with multiple authors
In MLA style, up to two authors are included in citations. List them in the order they appear in the source, separated by commas, and don’t invert the second author’s name.

**MLA journal citation: 2 authors**

Works Cited:    Eve, Martin Paul, and Joe Street. “The Silicon Valley Novel.” Literature & History, vol. 27, no. 1, May 2018, pp. 81-97, doi:10.1177/0306197318755680.
In-text citation:   (Eve and Street 84)

For more information, check out [this article](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/website-citation/#:%7E:text=An%20MLA%20website%20citation%20includes,title%20of%20the%20page%20instead) and [this article](https://www.scribbr.com/mla/journal-citation/).